# Regex for XXYXX

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression for Java to find digits structured like this:

```
XXYXX or XYYYX
```

So results could be 66266 or 71117

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you need a regular expression for this? (a) That's not a regular language, and (b) it's probably easier to do in Java code anyway.

Comment: if what you're seaching is ONE regex, then I'm afraid you can't.

Comment: Actually, you should also clarify whether your input is *always* five characters, or whether it is variable length. That makes a huge difference.

Comment: it's nicer to use a regex stored in a property file than hidden in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest `(\d)\1\d\1\1` for the first case and `(\d)(\d)\2\2\1` for the second. Mixing them both with non-capturing groups:

```
(?:(\d)\1\d\1\1)|(?:(\d)(\d)\2\2\1)
```

Not sure how Java plays with Regex though.

Comment: I used these: (\d)\1\d\1\1 and (\d)(\d)\2\2\1, Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex:

```
input.matches("((\\d)\\1\\d\\1\\1|(\\d)(\\d)\\3\\3\\2)");
```

It uses back references to handle repeating numbers and the regex "or `(A|B)`

Note that this regex will match `99999`, which is allowable by your definition (ie `X` and `Y` may be the same digit).

Also note the escaped back slashes `\\` for specifying a single backslash in the regex in a java String.